# Hierachy of android:layout_width/ height between containers and views

Tags: android

What is the relationship between android:layout_width & android:layout_height in the container and the views contained within?

For instance if I have a LinearLayout with the layout width and height set to fill_parent, and I have a Button with those values set to wrap_content it uses the value from the Button, like the Button values overide the LinearLayout.

However if i swap them around so that the LinearLayout values are both wrap_content and the Button values are now fill_parent it still uses wrap_content, this time not overriding the values, but using the values supplied with the LinearLayout.

Could someone explain how they relate as this is very confusing to me?

Thanks

Kyros